# Conserved quantities of a simple Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Suppose the following Lagrangian with 2 degrees of freedom:

$$L = \frac{3}{2}\dot{q}^2_{1} \ + \frac{3}{2}\dot{q}^2_{2} \ + \dot{q}_{1}\dot{q}_{2}$$

My aim is to find all the conserved quantities of this system. I know that there will be 3 in total: 2 quantities corresponding to translational symmetry and 1 for rotational symmetry ( ignoring time symmetry). I already found the translational momenta. These are the conjugate momenta corresponding to the cyclic coördinates $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$, so $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{1}}$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{2}}$. Then I tried finding the rotational symmetry by looking for new coördinates (this is done by diagonalising the kinetic matrix or by just "seeing it"). These are:

$$\begin{cases}y_{1} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q_{1} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q_{2} \\
y_{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q_{1} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q_{2}   \end{cases}$$
Then I used the inverse transformation to get the Lagrangian in terms of these new coördinates:
$$L = \dot{y}^2_{1} + 2\dot{y}^2_{2}$$
Thus, as a result, elliminating the crossterms. However I fail to see the rotational symmetry and finding the corresponding conserved angular momentum. How can one find this in terms of the original coördinates ?

Comment: You are almost there. How about rotations in the $(y_1,\sqrt{2}y_2)$ plane?

Comment: If I regard this as in the $(y_{1}, \sqrt{2}y_{2})$ plane, then I can write the Lagrangian in polar coördinates $r = \sqrt{y^2_{1} + 2y^2_{2}}$ and $\theta$. Then since $\theta$ is absent in the Lagrangian, the quantity $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = 2(y^2_{1}+2y^2_{2})\dot{\theta}$ should be conserved. But what is $\dot{\theta}$ in terms of the original coördinates ?